# Как найти и заменить данные в JSON?

Tags: python

Получаю по api JSON такого вида:

```
[{
    "comments": 18,
    "idMembers": [
        "61f11c9f67ffdd60eca0e258",
        "621db63b462c867ee790e4f7",
        "6193c309a86ee2327a054b0d"
    ],
    "labels": [
        "метка 1",
        "метка 2"
    ],
    "name": "task 1",
    "start": "2022-07-28T01:00:00.000Z"
},
{
    "comments": 0,
    "idMembers": [
        "6193c309a86ee2327a054b0d"
    ],
    "labels": [
        "метка 2",
        "метка 3"
    ],
    "name": "task 2",
    "start": "2022-08-05T01:00:00.000Z"
}]
```

Есть вот такой словарь с данным по каждому idMembers:

```
userArray = {'621db63b462c867ee790e4f7': 'Иван',
             '61f11c9f67ffdd60eca0e258': 'Владимир',
             '59a7dbc4557c9b17edbc02fa': 'Руслан',
             '6193c309a86ee2327a054b0d': 'Максим',
             '61fcc437b431385175d8fbee': 'Александра'}
```

Нужно найти в json совпадения по idMembers и ключу userArray и заменить ключ (621db63b462c867ee790e4f7) на значение(Иван).

Т.е. нужно преобразовать json в словарь, получить по ключу idMembers список, обойти его, на каждой итерации проверять вхождение элемента в userArray, сгенерировать новый список из найденных элементов, записать его обратно в словарь.

json преобразовываю в словарь сразу при получении:

```
jsonData = jmespath.search(query, json.loads(response.text)) //jmespath запрос к json для фильтра данных
```

Далее не знаю как делать, по идее нужен цикл, типа:

```
for entry in jsonData:
    if entry['idMembers'] is userArray:
        ...
```

Помогите пожалуйста.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тут хорошо подойдёт *списковое сокращение* и метод словаря `get`, потому что нужно перебрать все `id` из списка и заменить те, которые есть в словаре, на значения из словаря:

```py
for item in jsonData:
    item['idMembers'] = [userArray.get(member, member) for member in item['idMembers']]
```

Результат:

```
[{'comments': 18,
  'idMembers': ['Владимир', 'Иван', 'Максим'],
  'labels': ['метка 1', 'метка 2'],
  'name': 'task 1',
  'start': '2022-07-28T01:00:00.000Z'},
 {'comments': 0,
  'idMembers': ['Максим'],
  'labels': ['метка 2', 'метка 3'],
  'name': 'task 2',
  'start': '2022-08-05T01:00:00.000Z'}]
```

Comment: А если вместо словаря второй объект это json вида [{"key":"1","id":"61f11c9f67ffdd60eca0e258"}].
Я также через Json.loads преобразовываю его в словарь, но когда пытаюсь применить метод гет, пишет AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Ну потому что это список, его нужно 
тоже перебирать через for